# How do I change the ssh port for the tooltwist destination server?

Tags: linux

I am trying to setup the destination server for tooltwist on a cloud but would like to tighten security.  One of the things I thought of doing is to change the ssh port other than the default 22.  How can I work that out? I am using an AMI Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As root user, edit

```
/etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

You will see a commented out line

```
#Port 22
```

Uncomment it and change the line to

```
Port 2023
```

Save the file.  Now, restart the sshd daemon.

```
service sshd restart
```